Google OAuth Consent screen always display account selection screen
I want to integrate Gmail API into an Android app. So far, the app consists of the following steps:

The user selects a google account using firebase authentication
A Cloud Function launches the OAuth consent screen in the background
The user is asked again to select the account (in a web browser this time)
The user receives the consent screen

I'd like to get rid of step 3, because my user has just selected which account he wants to use and reselecting it is redundant, but I can't. I tried to set login_hint: email, but it has no effect.
I leave here a code snippet of the cloud function that launches the consent screen:
const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
  ];

console.log(`Request body: ${request.body.data}`);
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(request.body.data)
  .then((decodedToken) => {
    const uid = decodedToken.uid;
    const email = decodedToken.email;
    const sub = decodedToken.sub;
    console.log(`Logged in email ${email}`)
    const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: scopes,
        include_granted_scopes: true,
        state: uid,
        prompt: "consent",
        login_hint: email
    });
    response.set('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=0, s-maxage=0');
    response.send({"data": authorizationUrl});
})


The login_hint should work, but I am not sure for Android. There are better methods such as https://developers.google.com/identity/android-credential-manager

Posting as a community wiki based on the previous comment:

The login_hint should work, but I am not sure for Android. There are better methods such as developers.google.com/identity/android-credential-manager.

